# How to bind the value (<p>John</p>) to the input of mat form field as John?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-ui, angular7

I want to kind of use innerHTML on the value which I recieve from backend and bind it to the matInput.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you receive HTML from the backend in the first place, instead of receiving structured data as JSON? You should fix that instead of implementing dirty workarounds.

Comment: It is a structure json which has a name field in it. The name field has values which has HTML markup in it.  I don't have the control on data which is coming in. This is just a mock scenario which I have created in the question.

Comment: Use the DOM API of the browser to create an element from this HTML, and use this same DOM API to then extract the text out of this element.

Comment: p.s: before it crosses your mind, security wise, make sure you avoid using `ViewChild`, `[innerHTML]` or such, to directly place values in the DOM.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please give an example.

Comment: `const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString('<p>Hello</p>', 'text/html');
console.log(doc.documentElement.innerText);`

Comment: Thank you for the example..but this removed the tags and didn't format as innerHTML. After reading more about this, i came to know you can't bind innerHTML to input fields. So, I had to create a fake input as a div as it was a read-only field.

Answer (score 0):

Angular binding protects you from XSS by escaping html/script in text. You need to DomSanitizer to return safe html for binding. Checkout it out https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: This is the after most step when I would be able to use the innerHTML.